# How can I display the image clicked on another div in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

How can I show an image clicked on another div that has larger size to display the image?

I have tried this many times and through many logics but after hours of hardwork i though to post it here.
Below is my code :

I need to display a clicked image in smaller slide to a large div display class named `largerimage`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").onclick(function()
    {
        $(".largerimage").show($this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to actually copy or move the image, or just show it? Maybe some HTML showing what you've got, and what you're expecting to get, would help

Comment: I have one larger image and  some 3 to 4  small images coming dynamically from database and when these small  images are hovered or clicked I  need them to be showed on a larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do.

```js
$("img").click(function(){
  $img = $(this).clone();
  $(".largerimage").show().html($img.removeAttr('width'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="100" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff"/>
<div class="largerimage"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry fellow peple none of this is what i want.I need the one same like ebay product description.:              http://www.ebay.com/itm/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-SCH-I545-16GB-Verizon-AT-T-GSM-UNLOCKED-Cell-Phone-A-/231601205004?var=&hash=item35ec81ef0c:m:mINqItb9TUzlpu_5l7di5TA

Comment: @AshAsley for that you can make use of some jquery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, It may help you

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').click(function(){
          $largeimage = $(this).clone().css({height:"300", width:"300"});
          $(".largerimage").html($largeimage);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img width="50" src="C:\Users\buffer\Pictures\a.jpg" />
    <img width="100" src="C:\Users\buffer\Pictures\b.png" />
    <img width="200" src="C:\Users\buffer\Pictures\c.png"/>
    <div class="largerimage"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are three images with unequal width that are showed as fixed width in larger div.

Comment: Thanks for help bro.

Comment: But I need the working same like ebay. Kindly check the link :               http://www.ebay.com/itm/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-SCH-I545-16GB-Verizon-AT-T-GSM-UNLOCKED-Cell-Phone-A-/231601205004?var=&hash=item35ec81ef0c:m:mINqItb9TUzlpu_5l7di5TA

Comment: Buddy if answer is helpful for you please accept and upvote

Comment: @AshAsley goto above link

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var height1 = $("div.first").height();
  var width1 = $("div.first").width();
  var area1 = height1*width1;
  var height2 = $("div.second").height();
  var width2 = $("div.second").width();
  var area2 = height2*width2;

  if (area1>area2) {
    $("div.first").click(function(){
      $("img").show();
    });
  }
  if (area2>area1) {
    $("div.second").click(function(){
      $("img").show();
    });
  }
});
```

check this [***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/3g8u02vh/4/)